# How to convert a manually created WPF Menuitem into a Template / Style Resource / Control Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles, menuitem

I have manualy created a MenuItem. Now I want it as a Template / Style Resource / Control Template - whatever the best is for this Task.

My MenuItem looks like this (I know short Code):

```
<MenuItem
x:Name="Quit"                           << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
Command="{Binding ShutdownCommand}">    << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
<MenuItem.Header>
    <StackPanel 
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock 
            Width="150" 
            Text="Quit ERD Builder"/>   << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
        <TextBlock 
            Width="80" 
            Margin="0,2,0,0" 
            TextAlignment="Right">
            <Border 
                Padding="4,0,4,0" 
                BorderBrush="#B0B0B0" 
                Background="#fff" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                CornerRadius="6">
                <TextBlock 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    Text="Alt+F4"       << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
                    FontSize="10" 
                    Foreground="#555" />
            </Border>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</MenuItem.Header>
<MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image 
        Width="16" 
        Height="16" 
        Margin="0,0,5,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage 
                UriSource="/ERDBuilder;component/icons/bw/102-walk.png" />  << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

The Lines I declared with `<< OUTSIDE TEMPLATE` are the Lines I want declare in the MenuItem and not in the `Template`.

I had have already tried some Styles but "Background" for e.g. wont work for some Reason. I am able to change the "FontSize" but not the "Background" Color:

```
<Style 
x:Key="TopTaskBarMenuitem" 
TargetType="MenuItem">
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffff00" />    << DONT WORK
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />           << WORKS
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />               << WORKS
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />             << WORKS
<Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>                      << WORKS
```

This is the Menu how it looks if I `XAML' it manually:

[Manualy created Menuitem](http://visualrequest.com/share/mi_manualy.png) (I am not allowed to upload Images here ?!)

And this is the Menuitem with the static Style Resource:

[Menuitem with Style Resource](http://visualrequest.com/share/mi_style_resource.png)

As you can see, the "Background" Color wont affect the Menuitem.

If I could wish me something I would have in the End something like this on the "Menuitem"-Side:

```
<MenuItem
Style="{StaticResource TopTaskBarMenuitem}"                     << TEMPLATE / STYLE BINDING
x:Name="Quit"                                                   << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
Command="{Binding ShutdownCommand}"                             << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
MyHeaderText="Quit ERD Builder"/>                               << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
MyShortcutText="Alt+F4"                                         << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
MyUriSource="/ERDBuilder;component/icons/bw/102-walk.png" />    << OUTSIDE TEMPLATE
```

Thanks a lot to all they will Help!

PS: The last Codeline are missing on all three Code-Postings here. I dont know why. I am not able to fix this.

Dirk

Answer (score 2):

To acquire this you have to create your *own* control deriving from MenuItem.

All you need to do is create the control class using DependencyProperties to make use of all its benefits, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) for more:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
    {
        public string MyHeaderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyHeaderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyHeaderTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyHeaderTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyHeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public string MyShortcutText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyShortcutTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyShortcutTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyShortcutTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyShortcutText", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public string MyUriSource
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyUriSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyUriSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyUriSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyUriSource", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));
    }
}
```

Now you are able to instantiate your control, but you still need to *"retemplate"* it:

```
<mc:MyMenuItem MyHeaderText="Quit ERD Builder" MyShortcutText="Alt+F4" MyUriSource="/ERDBuilder;component/icons/bw/102-walk.png">
    <mc:MyMenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="mc:MyMenuItem">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=MyHeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mc:MyMenuItem}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="80" Margin="0,2,0,0" TextAlignment="Right">
                                    <Border Padding="4,0,4,0" BorderBrush="#B0B0B0" Background="#fff" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6">
                                        <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=MyShortcutText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mc:MyMenuItem}}" FontSize="10" Foreground="#555" />
                                    </Border>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MyUriSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=mc:MyMenuItem}}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </mc:MyMenuItem.Style>
</mc:MyMenuItem>
```

Don't forget to reference the namespace of this new control in your window (or wherever you may put this control) tag:

```
xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:MyControls"
```

It's possible to insert this style in a ResourceDictionary so you don't need to reference it everytime you use this control.

```
<Style TargetType="mc:MyMenuItem">
    <!-- Style comes here -->
</Style>
```

Then you can acquire what you asked:

```
<mc:MyMenuItem MyHeaderText="Quit ERD Builder" MyShortcutText="Alt+F4" MyUriSource="/ERDBuilder;component/icons/bw/102-walk.png" />
```

I wish it can help you!

Comment: Hi Wiley. I tried it and I think it works fine. But the URI for the Icon doesnt work. I get the Error after Compiling: XmlParseException: System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" has raised an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

### CoreStyle.xaml

The part from the Template / Style:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ctrl:Bitmap>
      <ctrl:Bitmap.Source>
        <!-- This doesnt work: --> <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=MenuIcon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ctrl:MainMenuItem}}" />
        <!-- This Still works fine: <BitmapImage UriSource="../Resources/Icons/16/page_add.png" />-->
      </ctrl:Bitmap.Source>
    </ctrl:Bitmap>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

### MainMenuItem.cs

The Custom Control class that derives from MenuItem:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ErdBuilder.Shell.Controls
{
class MainMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public ICommand MenuCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(MenuCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainMenuItem));

    public string MenuText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MenuTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuText", typeof(string), typeof(MainMenuItem));

    public string MenuShortcut
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MenuShortcutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuShortcutProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuShortcutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuShortcut", typeof(string), typeof(MainMenuItem));

    public string MenuIcon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MenuIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuIconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuIconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuIcon", typeof(string), typeof(MainMenuItem));

}
```

}

I also tried this:

```
public BitmapImage MenuIcon
    {
        get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)GetValue(MenuIconProperty))); }
        set { SetValue(MenuIconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuIconProperty =     DependencyProperty.Register("MenuIcon", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(MainMenuItem));
```

### Shell.xaml

And finaly the Part where I try to use the new Control:

```
<ctrl:MainMenuItem x:Name="TestMenu"
  MenuCommand="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}"
  MenuText="New..."
  MenuShortcut="Ctr+N"
  MenuIcon="../Resources/Icons/16/page_add.png"/>
```

Comment: The MenuCommand Property also doesnt work. I can set it and there is no Error, but it does not recognize my Settings for the MenuCommand Value.