# subclassing a wpf popup control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, popup, subclassing

I was looking for a way to drag/move a PopUp Control and I found this answer

[Drag wpf popup control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170666)

unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to subclass a PopUp control, I tried creating a custom control and inheriting from PopUp but It didn't seem right to me.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Didn't seem right" is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: What I understood from the answer is that the subclassing consist of xaml and codebehind partial class. but what I get is only a class and it generate some kind of resource dictionary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do exactly what you told.

A class inheriting from the control class you want to modify, thus you will be able to make your own properties.
If you want to *"retemplate"* that control you'll need a place to store the styles, templates, and so on.

Take a look at this answer below to see further, its about changing a MenuItem control but you are going to use the same tricks.

[How to convert a manually created WPF Menuitem into a Template / Style Resource / Control Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955983/how-to-convert-a-manually-created-wpf-menuitem-into-a-template-style-resource/14244560#14244560)